# Google assistant on raspberry pi wont't work after reboot

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I seem to not be able to run the assistant after rebooting the Pi. I can reload all of the python and samples and then it will work until I shut it down. My friend is having the same trouble as well. Any one else?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you need to run "python3 -m venv env" before running python -m googlesamples.assistant. I wonder if there is any way to have this work right on power up...

Comment: You can reuse the virtual environment after creating it.